# I can't reach my layout file in my adapter with R.layout.(file_name)

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to add custom layout to change my selected item text in my spinner. But I couldn't reach my layout file with R.layout.my_selected_item in my array adapter. It is saying "Unresolved reference: my_selected_item".

[You can see error here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gC7q.png)

ArrayAdapter:

```
val sortedCurrencySymbolsList = listOf("BTC", "ETH", "XRP", "USDC", "BNB",
            "DOGE", "LTC", "MATIC", "DYDX", "ADA").sorted()
        ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            R.layout.my_selected_item,
            sortedCurrencySymbolsList
        ) .also {
            it.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            binding.spinnerCrypto.adapter = it
        }
```

my_selected_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

I tried clean/rebuild and invalidate caches restart but it didn't help.
I imported "import com.menesdurak.virtualcrypto.R.layout.my_selected_item" and it didn't help too.
I opened new project, tried to add new layout in there and it worked. But in my project, Android Studio don't let me do it. Somehow in my project it don't let me add my custom layout.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: What `R` have you imported?

Comment: I sometimes get error such as this. Usually, clear cache/restarting AS works. Also, check to see if you are importing an R.whatever. If so, delete it and restart. Not sure why that is, but sometimes that works for me.

Comment: After your suggestions I deleted my old R import which was "import android.R" and replaced with "import com.(my_package).R" now it is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please up vote the answer that helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check your imports I think you are importing the wrong **R** package.

Comment: I deleted my old R import which was "import android.R" and replaced with "import com.(my_package).R" now it is working. Thanks a lot!